# Gunicorn doesn't work

Tags: python, django, heroku, virtualenv, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my django app on heroku. After following the steps instructed by the official document, the dyno I launched always crashes. Then I went through the whole process, and I think the problem might lie on the gunicorn part. 
Following the instruction, I set the Procfile as 'web: unicorn hellodjango.wsgi', and when I $foreman start, it only shows "21:21:07 web.1  | started with pid 77969". It didn't say where the web is launched. 
Then I tried to test whether gunicorn is working well. So I tried: "$gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi:application", it indeed doesn't work.

I think the path is correct because in current folder there's a hellodjango folder and inside there's the file wsgi.py.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

One of the changes in later versions of gunicorn includes not logging to stdout/stderr.  Add the argument --log-file=XXX, then examine that log file for what port it's running on.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your Procfile to:

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 0):

write this in your Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi --log-file -
```

it will log everything to the screen like this:

```
(your_virtualenv)[~/Projects/myproj]$ foreman start
17:03:57 web.1  | started with pid 79137
17:03:58 web.1  | 2014-10-16 17:03:58 [79137] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.0.0
17:03:58 web.1  | 2014-10-16 17:03:58 [79137] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (79137)
17:03:58 web.1  | 2014-10-16 17:03:58 [79137] [INFO] Using worker: sync
17:03:58 web.1  | 2014-10-16 17:03:58 [79140] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 79140
```